# Any DVB-S2 sample streams, publicly available?

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, sampling, demodulation

I'm working on a DVB-S2 receiver and I'd like to be able to test a part of the DSP chain with real-world signals, but getting good sample streams from a digitizer is not terribly easy.

Can anyone point me to DVB-S2 sample streams available on-line, i.e. digitizer output? I'm particularly interested in **adaptive/variable coded/modulated** (ACM/VCM) streams, with at least one mod-cod switch. It can basically be of any length, raw I+Q streams, VITA 49 or anything similar.

A good simulator would be a distant second choice.